# how to avoid overfittig with xgboost and how to increase accuracy

Tags: machine-learning, classification, cross-validation, overfitting, boosting

I am doing a binary classification problem, I got to train 85% accuracy, but  test accuracy is 72%, I tried different parameters, Cross valid, But overfitting doesn't change,
please help me on how to reduce overfitting.

This is my parameters code:

```
   params={
     "learning_rate"    : [0.05, 0.10, 0.15, 0.20, 0.25, 0.30 ] ,
     "max_depth"        : [ 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 15],
     "min_child_weight" : [ 1, 3, 5, 7 ],
     "gamma"            : [ 0.0, 0.1, 0.2 , 0.3, 0.4 ],
     "colsample_bytree" : [ 0.3, 0.4, 0.5 , 0.7 ]

    }
x_clf=XGBClassifier()
random_search=RandomizedSearchCV(x_clf,param_distributions=params,n_iter=5,scoring='roc_auc',n_jobs=-1,cv=5,verbose=3)
```

This is my cross-validation code:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
errxgb=[]
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10,shuffle=True,random_state=None)
# X is the feature set and y is the target
for train_index, test_index in skf.split(X,y):
    X_train, X_test = X.iloc[train_index], X.iloc[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
    random_search.fit(X_train,y_train,eval_set=[(X_train,y_train),(X_test, y_test)], early_stopping_rounds=100,verbose=3)
    preds=random_search.predict_proba(X_test)[:,-1]
    print("err_xgb: ",roc_auc_score(y_test,preds))
    errxgb.append(roc_auc_score(y_test,preds))
    p= random_search.predict(test_df)
```

Comment: How large is your data? In small(ish) data randomness in evaluation can have a large effect. Also, are there some reasons why your cross-validation may be suboptimal, e.g. is there some structure in the data that should be taken into account when setting up your cross-validation? E.g. if you are predicting sales for new customers, you should not have records for the same customer in both the training and validation part of a 
validation split. Similarly, if you are forecasting the future, you should not have records in the past of the validation records in the training part of a CV split.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you do nested cv to evaluate the performances of each split but I don't see any sort of averaging to come up with a final estimate. I'm assuming you average accuracies found for each outer split.

More importantly, it won't probably matter how large your hyper-parameter search space is because `RandomizedSearchCV` has only `n_iter=5` iterations, which means you *randomly* sample only $5$ combinations from a total of $6\times8\times4\times5\times4 = 3840$ combinations. When you sample only $5$ of these, it's highly probable that you end up with a bad set of hyper-parameters since the search space is not spanned well.

You may want to use a smaller space with broader steps, and then re-search around promising areas at finer resolution. Or, you may also want to try [Bayesian HPO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperparameter_optimization#/Bayesian_optimization) implemented in [skopt](https://scikit-optimize.github.io/) (`BayesSearchCV` class), which is typically more efficient than complete grid search and surely better from random search.